# sender.identifier isEqualToString

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've two modal controllers with button close at the top navigation bar of each.
I want to intercept the correct close button in my main view controller.
Unfortunately this code doesn't work, why ?

```
   - (IBAction)close:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender {

      if ([sender.identifier isEqualToString: @"FirstModalClose"]) {
        NSLog(@"FirstModalClose");
     }

       if ([sender.identifier isEqualToString: @"SecondModalClose"]) {
        NSLog(@"SecondModalClose");
     }
}
```

Comment: When i click on close on first modal controller it doesn't write in NSLog FirstModalClose and When i click on close in second modal controller it doesn't write in NSLog SecondModalClose

Comment: Does it get into that method at all? Does the close button work? Have you used breakpoints in the method and checked what the sender is? The trouble is, there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted, so the problem must be elsewhere - either you haven't set the identifier on your segue or you haven't connected the buttons correctly. It's impossible to know from the information in your question.

Comment: Its Better to identify button by their tag property .
you can assign it like button.tag = 100.

Comment: I've added some breakpoint and when click the 2 close button i go inside IBAction. Unfortunately i don't go in the 2 if statements. Just to clarified: i'd like to come back from the 2 modal view into the first controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply had to insert FirstModalClose and SecondModalClose in the proper fields :(
I inserted FirstModalClose and SecondModalClose in Storyboard Segue and not in Storyboard Unwind Segue.
Now all work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the type `IBAction` suggest that this method is triggered (if at all) by a GUI element, not a segue. Thus, the sender is propably an `UIControl` not an `UIStoryboardSegue`.

Maybe you want use `UIViewController`'s method `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`. There, you get both: the sender **and** the segue.

Comment: So i don't have to connect the close button in modal view (navigation bar) into my first view controller ? I've read that every time i need to make an unwind i've always add this code - (IBAction)close:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender { }

Comment: me silly ! i insert the names FirstModalClose and SecondModalClose in Storyboard Segue and not in Storyboard Unwind Segue.